# Keeping multiple Shell Script into one to backup log files

Tags: bash, shell, logging, sh, unix-timestamp

I have the bellow script to backup the 10th number of server logs.

```
#!/bin/sh

filePath="/var/opt/AppServer/App/instances/default/logs/error.log.10"
backupDir="/backup_app-N/app/default/logs"

### Process Starts ####

md5File=`md5sum $filePath| awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
#echo $md5File
fileName=`basename $filePath| sed 's/.[0-9]\+//g'`
#echo $fileName
while [ 1 ]
do
    md5Previous=$md5File
    md5File=` md5sum $filePath| awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
    #echo "Previous: $md5Previous  Current: $md5File"
    if [ $md5Previous != $md5File ]; then
                    exe_date=`date '+%m%d%y_%H%M%S'`
                    cp $filePath $backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date
                    echo "COPY :"$filePath" as " $backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date    
                    gzip $backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date
    fi
    sleep 3
done
```

I have few more same scripts for the same functionality, but only change the **filePath**. 
Now I want to make one script to run do the same tasks. (keeping same logic in one script , not in concurrent)

I did the following things - I make one config file - `test.config` , where I put all the **filePath** and read the paths from the config files.

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ]
do
while read path
do
filePath="$path"
backupDir="/backup_app-N/app/default/logs"

### Process Starts ####

md5File=`md5sum $filePath| awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
#echo $md5File "md"
fileName=`basename $filePath| sed 's/.[0-9]\+//g'`
#echo $fileName "file"

    md5Previous=$md5File
    md5File=` md5sum $filePath| awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
           #echo "Previous: $md5Previous  Current: $md5File"
    if [ $md5Previous != $md5File ]; then

                    exe_date=`date '+%m%d%y_%H%M%S'`
                    cp $filePath $backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date
                    echo "COPY :"$filePath" as " $backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date
                    gzip $backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date
    fi        

done < test.conf
sleep 3
done
```

And in the `test.config`, I put the path like

```
/var/opt/AppServer/App/instances-0/default/logs/error.log.10
/var/opt/AppServer/App/instances-1/default/logs/error.log.10
/var/opt/AppServer/App/instances-2/default/logs/error.log.10
/var/opt/AppServer/App/instances-3/default/logs/error.log.10
```

While I'm running the scripts separately, I am getting the result. But my modified one is not working properly.

I think the problem is for the `while loop`. Once it gets into, it takes 4 path and execute for the 2nd time, the loop starts from the beginning, it can't preserve the last state !!!

I have questions - What would be the probable solutions ?

Is my approach good to run several scripts together in this way?

Can I have any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Agree about `logrotate`. But looking at what  you have: `cp $filePath$backupDir/$fileName-$exe_date` ? Don't you want a space char. in between $filePath and $backupDir? Also, I don't see you modify value of backupDir to change `backup_app-N` (the `N`) part. Is that as intended? Good luck

Comment: @shellter - Thanks to point out that. It is not intended. It is my mistake while I did it here. I edited.

Comment: @shellter - Thanks to point out that. It is not intended. It is my mistake while I did it here. I edited. I didn't get your `backup_app-N` thing. We have North and South Server. here - 'N` is for North backup server.